# How to detect Bluetooth adapter with Electron?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bluetooth, electron

Is it possible to detect in Electron, if PC (Mac or Linux) has Bluetooth adapter connected? I'm using "bluetooth-serial-port" library for Bluetooth communication. If BT adapter is not connected to PC the application keeps reloading.

This is how the app is trying to find devices.

```
var btSerial = new (require('bluetooth-serial-port')).BluetoothSerialPort();

try {
    btSerial.inquire();
}
catch (e) {
    callback(new Error('something bad happened ' + e));
}
btSerial.on('failure', function(error){console.log(error);});
```

Comment: How does your implementation look like?

Comment: Do you get any error message in the console while the application is reloading? Btw, your last row is incomplete, it should end with `console.log(error)});`

Comment: yes, missed. The application just hangs. Developer tools show message that they are disconnected from the main process. That's it.

Comment: Okey. And the code you pasted are being run in the main process? Have you tried to remove the code, line by line, to identify what part the hangs the application?

Comment: yes, it runs in the main process. The line causes the problem is btSerial.inquire(); when I comment it, the application works properly.

Comment: Does your computer has a bluetooth device installed?

Comment: Have you checkout [this](https://github.com/aalhaimi/electron-web-bluetooth) project for a different approach (using web bluetooth)?

Comment: on one PC with installed bluetooth adapter it works perfectly. On the other without bluetooth it doesn't. No, haven't seen this project. I'll check it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[According to this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/eelcocramer/node-bluetooth-serial-port/issues/136) the `bluetooth-serial-port` will crash when the computer doesn't have any bluetooth device installed.

As far as I know, Electron doesn't have any API for bluetooth. Depending on your use case, you can use [web bluetooth](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/07/interact-with-ble-devices-on-the-web) to use bluetooth (or just check if the computer has bluetooth). Check out [electron-web-bluetooth on GitHub](https://github.com/aalhaimi/electron-web-bluetooth) to see a working example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use inquireSync() to avoid a crash

```
try {
    btSerial.inquireSync();
}
catch (e){
    callback(new Error('something bad happened ' + e));
}
```